# Why is my very minimal WPF app hanging?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013, wpf-controls, bing-maps

I have what is as yet a very minimal (just started) WPF app that uses Bing Maps. This is all there is to it so far:

```
<Window x:Class="DataMapper.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Data Mapper" Height="532" Width="798" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" >
    <Grid>
        <m:Map x:Name="dataMapper" ZoomLevel="10" CredentialsProvider="MyKeyWhichWorksInWindows8Apps" Mode="Aerial" ></m:Map>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Yet, when I run it does display a map (very faintly, I might add), but it is unresponsive/hangs. I had to Ctrl+Alt+Delete to get it to shut down.

Comment: Not sure on this one. Never had anyone report an issue like this for the WPF control. Maybe try taking a look at the event viewer in Windows to see if maybe there are errors being thrown somewhere. Maybe a graphics card issue.

Comment: Running it again, I can get past the hanging/frozen part, but I still so only a faint outline of the map, and my bottomappbar is uninvokable (Windows + Z on my laptop does not conjure it up). I whin[g]ed about that here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27455854/what-might-cause-my-bottomappbar-to-not-display

Comment: Are you behind a firewall by chance? If so, that might be blocking access to the Bing Maps servers. That would cause issues with the map authenticating and the tiles loading which could be a possible cause for the hanging. If you are behind a firewall contact the Bing Map support team by going to the following link and using the developer support tools on the right side column: http://microsoft.com/maps/licensing

Comment: It all works fine with my Windows Store app (the map shows up just dandy). I've tried to also incorporate Bing Maps into a WPF app and a Winforms app, and in this case, I just get the opaque map. Also, this is from home, so I don't think there's any heavy-duty firewall.

Comment: How about trying the update WPF control. A new release was pushed out last week, complete with a lot of bug fixes. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27165

Comment: Okay; this turned out to be a Visual Studio install needy of being Repaired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the updated WPF control which has a bunch of bug fixes: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27165

There is also a Nuget package available now: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF/1.0.0.3